# Best postgis distance query

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to find the fastest way to get a count for properties with a radius.  I've seen some of the other similar question.  Does any one know why the third query gives such different results?  It is super fast.

**Slow**

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM property
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(geom_pt, ST_MakePoint(-104.989879,39.736355))<=2000;
```

**count=2665**

**Very Slow**

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM property
WHERE ST_Distance(geom_pt, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-104.989879, 39.736355),4326)::geography)<=2000;
```

**count=2665**

**Very Fast**

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM property
WHERE ST_Within(geom_pt,ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-104.989879, 39.736355), 4326), 3857), 2000), 4326));
```

**count=1794**

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you want [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) which will use a GIST index.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM property
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  geom_pt, -- make sure this is also geography
  ST_MakePoint(-104.989879, 39.736355)::geography,
  2000     -- note distance in meters.
);
```

You also don't have to set srid to 4326 on geography. It's the default.

If you don't have the index,

```
CREATE INDEX ON property USING gist(geom_pt);
VACUUM property;
```

You can `CLUSTER` on `geom_pt` too.